# JMeter proxy is blocking the login

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I am trying to record a test script with JMeter for an internal website hosted on company intranet. I can record only till navigation of the login page, submitting username/password, and click on login button. The login page reloads all the time. Nothing else happens.

Steps to reproduce ->

1) I started the JMTeter HTTP Test script recorder

2) I changed the browser settings to point it to the proxy.

3) Navigated to login page, keyed in username/password, and clicked login

4) The login page reloads, nothing else happens.

I tried it on all the browser. It's same everywhere. I recorded testes on gmail and facebook successfully. I did not face any issue there for navigation. Please help me. Is it an issue with the server where the site is hosted?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of login authentication that you used in your internal website? Is it the same authentication as gmail or facebook (using login form, then compare it to database)? Or is it Active Directory User (windows account) authentication (usually, there is browser popup to enter username and password).

You can try this:

1. Start the JMTeter HTTP Test script recorder
2. changed the browser settings to point it to the proxy
3. Navigate to login page, keyed in username/password, and clicked login. From this point, you will have sampler for login step
4. changed the browser settings to not using JMeter proxy
5. Navigate to login page, keyed in username/password, and clicked login. It should be working
6. changed the browser settings to point it to the proxy again
7. Do the rest recording normally to get the rest scenarios.

I hope that will help you.